# How can i compare one value to multiple value in database in php?

Tags: php, sql

my problem is i have one field in database which have multiple vaue for example i have one table which name is users in which i have two field one is id and another field is hobbies. table structure is like this:
user table:

```
       id      hobbies
    -------- -------------
       1      1,2
       2       2 
       3      2,3
```

hobbies table:

```
          id      hobbies
    -------- -------------
       1        singing
       2        dancing 
       3        reading
```

now my problem is i want all user which hobby is dancing which is id 2 from hobbies table.but my query is only give user 3 as output which is wrong here is my php code:

```
    $scheck = $_REQUEST['scheck'];//$scheck is array of hobbies like 1,2
    if (!empty($scheck)) {
            if (strstr($scheck, ',')) {
                $data3 = explode(',', $scheck);
                $sarray = array();
                foreach ($data3 as $c) {
                    $sarray[] = "t1.hobbies = $c";
                }
                $WHERE[] = '(' . implode(' OR ', $sarray) . ')';
                $inner = ' JOIN hobbies AS t3 ON t1.hobbies = t3.id ';
            } else {
                $WHERE[] = '(t1.hobbies = ' . $scheck . ')';
                $inner = ' JOIN hobbies AS t3 ON t1.hobbies = t3.id ';
            }
        }
      $w = implode(' AND ', $WHERE);
      if (!empty($w)) $w = 'WHERE ' . $w;
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT  t1 . * FROM  `users` AS t1 $inner $w
```

please give me some solutions for my problem.

Comment: Wrong table design. You should be inserting data by row.

Comment: Yeah you really should have a single row that contains a users id and the hobby id.  So for a user with 3 hobbies you would have 3 rows.  This would also make it easier to remove a hobby from a user.

Comment: You cannot join `ON t1.hobbies = t3.id ` as t1 cotains multiple values where as t3 contains it as an integer.

Comment: okay.. but now i design this table in project and i can't change it.. so there is no possible solution for this problem?

Comment: See my answer. That may help. I guess, it will not be that hard to change the table structure. For future purpose, it'll make other related works easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the datatype of user table for column hobbies.
I guess if its varchar then query writing will be difficult.

My suggession will be create a new table for users and and hobbies relation where add multiple entries of users for each hobby.

thanks

Comment: datatype of user table for column hobbies is varchar(255)